# Get relative path of a file to a reference directory in linux shell

Tags: bash, sh, posix

I am trying to get working a function in bash or at least in POSIX for getting the relative path for a file taking as a reference the parent directory.

I hope the function would return the relative path:

```sh
get_relative_path(){
  file="$1"
  main_dir="$2"
  ...
  # I do not know how to get it 
  ...
  return "$path"
}

# and it would be called as:
f="docs/readme.html"
main_dir="./"

path="$(get_relative_path "$f" "$main_dir")"
echo "$path" # ..

f="docs/2021/readme.html"
main_dir="./"

path="$(get_relative_path "$f" "$main_dir")"
echo "$path" # ../..
```

My working directory would look as this:

```sh
.
├── docs
│   └── readme.html
├── pdf
├── imgs
├── index.html
├── sitemap.xml
├── styles.css
└── toggle.js
```

The goal of this is to make a reference in the "readme.html" file to the "style.css" upper in the working directory tree.
The same way I would like to get the relative path of "./index.html" which is in "./", so the reference relative would point as "style.css" in the output HTML file.

I hope my explanation has been understood

Edit:
I get working it with this function:

```sh
realpath_f(){
    realpath --relative-to="$2" "$1" | tr '/' '\n'$ | sed '0,/../{//d;}' | tr '\n' '/' 
}
```

With it, it can get the relative path:

```sh
realpath_f "$HOME" "/tmp" # home/$USER
# or for a file
realpath_f "$HOME" "$HOME/.ssh/know_hosts" # ..
```

Comment: You should use `echo` in the function, not `return`.

Comment: Find the common directory prefix of both paths and remove it from both. The result will start with as many `../` as you have directories in `$f`, and end with the remainder of `$main_dir`. Ignore any `./` at the end of `$main_dir`

Comment: e.g. if `f=foo/bar/x/y/z` and `main_dir=foo/bar/a/b`, you remove `foo/bar/` from both. Then it becomes `../../a/b`

Comment: `realpath --relative-to` is not posix, and not available everywhere. `'\n'$` What is that `$` doing there? `0,/../` is also not posix sed, a gnu extension. TBH if you are looking for posix, you end up with a C program. If you want it to be portable, call old perl or python2. And, anyway, your method will be good enough _on any modern linux_.